# Maximilian, The Scapula, and magic revealed to be science

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book once and would like to find it again.

It was about a thief, Maximilian. And a wizard. And some other characters.

They practice what they think is magic, that is eventually revealed to be science.

There is the leader of a city. His name is "The Scapula".

I think it was a series of 3-4 books.

Can't remember much else. Hope that's enough.

Answer (score 4):

Mayer Alan Brenner's *The Dance of Gods*

Ref:

- http://www.mayerbrenner.com
- http://www.feedbooks.com/list/24/the-dance-of-gods

Books include:

1. Spell of Catastrophe
2. Spell of Intrigue
3. Spell of Fate
4. Spell of Apocalypse